# ipython won't run on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ipython

After installing ipython on Windows via `pip install ipython`, I am unable to run it and receive the following error.

```
> ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyreadline>=1.7.1
```

pyreadline was installed when ipython was via pip, but `pip freeze` shows warnings about the SVN location

```
> pip freeze
Warning: cannot find svn location for pyreadline==1.7.1.dev-r0
...
ipython==0.13.1
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
pyreadline==1.7.1.dev-r0
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall the version of pyreadline pulled when ipython was installed (`pip uninstall pyreadline`) and download and install `pyreadline-1.7.1.win32-py2.7.‌exe` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyreadline

Comment: I'd actually recommend downloading `ipython` from that site as well. Bookmark it, it's a great resource for scientific computing packages for windows. Make sure you get Numpy-MKL as well!

Comment: I use that site for curses support too so I can use bpython on Windows as well (which I prefer over ipython) - http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/windows.html

Comment: I got into using iPython because it works with [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) in [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), and I can customize all the syntax highlighting myself. Combined with [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) and [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) it makes for a pretty good environment. I'll definitely check out bpython, though, because the expected parameter list functionality looks pretty cool...